# Issues connecting redis from .net 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, .net-framework-version, azure-redis-cache

I'm new with all of these. can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.
Connecting redis from .net framework 4.7.2 - redisSessionStateProvider using TLS mutual auth and getting the below error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> Timeout performing EVAL (6000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown,
> serverEndpoint: serverName:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available,
> clientName: SessionStateProvider, IOCP:
> (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.6.48.48654 (Please take a
> look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause
> timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout
> performing EVAL (6000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw:
> SpinningDown, serverEndpoint: serverName:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of
> 10 available, clientName: SessoinStateProvider, IOCP:
> (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.6.48.48654 (Please take a
> look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause
> timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the
> execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
> and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
> stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL (6000ms), inst: 0, qu:
> 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, serverEndpoint:
> serverName:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName:
> SessionStateProvider, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.6.48.48654 (Please take a
> look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause
> timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)]
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl(Message
> message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:1854    StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs:1501    Microsoft.Web.Redis.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Eval>b__0() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:68 Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.OperationExecutor(Func`1
> redisOperation) in
> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:95
> Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1
> redisOperation) in
> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:122
> Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script,
> String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs) in
> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:68
> Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.Set(ISessionStateItemCollection
> data, Int32 sessionTimeout) in
> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisConnectionWrapper.cs:137
> Microsoft.Web.Redis.d__25.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisSessionStateProvider.cs:433
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62
> Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.d__80.MoveNext()
> +812    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62
> Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.d__82.MoveNext() +323
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +62
> Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
> +58    System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +417    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +158

Web.config:

```
<add settingsClassName="RedisConfig" settingsMethodName="GetConnectionString" name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" ssl="true" accessKey="somelengthypassword"/>
```

RedisConfig.cs:

```
      static RedisConfig()
        {
    
            try
            {
                var options = new ConfigurationOptions
                {
                    EndPoints = { "serverName:6379" },
                    ClientName = "SessionStateProvider",
                    User = "acl-username",                      
                    Password = "somelengthypassword",
                    Ssl = true,
                   // SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                    AllowAdmin = true,
                    AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                    ConnectTimeout = 10000,
                    SyncTimeout = 6000,
                    ConnectRetry = 3,
                    CheckCertificateRevocation = false
                };
    
               
                options.CertificateSelection += delegate
                {
                    
                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\temp\\myclientcert.pfx", "test");
                    return certificate;
                };
    
                conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    
        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            
    
            var config = conn.Configuration;
            return conn.Configuration;
    
            
        }
```

Storing data:
**Index.aspx**

```
 protected void GreetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = NameTextBox.Text;
        Session.Add("MyName", name);
        Session.Add("SessionTime", DateTime.Now);
        Response.Redirect("~/Result.aspx");
    }
```

Result.aspx:

```
public partial class Result : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object name = Session["MyName"];
            object time = Session["SessionTime"];
            if (name != null && time != null)
                NameLabel.Text = "Hi! " + (string)name + ", your last session state storing time was: " + time;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- In Redis, we can use `ConnectionString`  and provide all the parameters

```cs
<connectionStrings>  
   <add name = "MySessionStateStore" connectionString="****,allowAdmin=True,connectTimeout=10000,ssl=true,abortConnect=False,connectRetry=3,AbortOnConnectFail=3,CheckCertificateRevocation=false"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And Specify the Redis `connectionStringName` to provider's section:

```cs
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateStoreProvider"> 
    <providers>
      <add name="RedisSessionStateStoreProvider"       type="RedisAspNetProviders.SessionStateStoreProvider, RedisAspNetProviders"
           connectionStringName="MySessionStateStore" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>
```

***OR***
Can use existing multiplexer.

- If we instantiate the Multiplexer like you have done in `RedisConfig.cs` , no need to call that setting in `web.config`.

Calling the ***`ConnectionString`***

````cs
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySessionStateStore"].ConnectionString;```
````

[image]

References taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/alex-simonov/RedisAspNetProviders)